# Satisfying Demand

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Certain expressions rely on pairs of words. We have some word-pairs as such:

> Quench Thirst
>   Sate Hunger
>   Satisfy Desire
>   Satisfy Demand

It seems strange to me that *satisfy* would be used for both *desire* and *demand*, though the two words are mostly synonymous. At the same time, *satisfy* is a rather general term — we can *satisfy* many things, but we can *quench* only *thirst*. So is there a more specific word than *satisfy* for either of these, a word that creates a word-pair that 'fits better'?

Comment: How about Attain Desire and Meet Demand?

Comment: Well, one could _quench a fire_, but since that is often done with water, perhaps one is simply _quenching a fire's thirst_.

Comment: That's awkward usage --- you *extinguish* a fire. (Though I appreciate the humour of your comment.)

Comment: @Newb http://i.imgur.com/ki2e3Zd.jpg

Comment: How about Fulfill a Desire (like one's other fantasies), Meet a Demand (like @VijayaRagavan)? I think one attains _the object of_ one's Desires, but not the Platonic Desires themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You need to realize that 'Thirst' and 'Hunger' are also specific needs, while 'Desire' and 'Demand' are very generic. They could range from a spiritual quest to meet God to a baser need like a new dress.

Hence, 'satisfy' by its very definition, is the proverbial one size that fits all!

Answer (score 1):

Two words that are often paired are *fullfill demands* (of course, you could just as easily say *fulfill desire*).

Comment: Yes, I thought about this as well.

Answer (score 1):

> satisfy demand

[Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com.mx/scholar?hl=en&q=%22satisfy+demand%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) > 16,100
[Yahoo Search](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AiVC1SLeFqLY4YKyxu30warak7MF?p=%22satisfy+demand%22&fr=ush-edu) > 65,900

> meet demand

[Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com.mx/scholar?q=%22meet+demand%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) > 51,000
[Yahoo Search](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AvG1a15r07BtpXDecAsf0SCbvZx4?p=%22meet+demand%22&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-900) > 1,200,000

> a [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satisfy+demand%2Cmeet+demand&year_start=1970&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csatisfy%20demand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeet%20demand%3B%2Cc0) showing occurrence of both terms in Google Books' database.
>
> http://puu.sh/62RuZ.png

#### Thanks to [aeismail](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/60389/aeismail) and [Vilmar](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/54112/vilmar)

> ## In conclusion

Looking at the nature of the results given by the queries done at Google and Yahoo, I assume that "meeting demand" is an expression ideally used in the economical contexts, while "satisfying a demand" belongs to the sphere of forensic jargon.

Answer (score 0):

If we keep in mind that all of these words have overlapping secondary and tertiary definitions/meanings, then all of these suggestions make sense.

Put differently, each single word can never **fully** narrow down your intended meaning in the reader's mind. It is the Verb-Noun *Pair* that conveys your intention.

So:

- "Desires Satisfied" *legitimately* implies a shortcoming-made-good, of regaining equilibrium up until Satisfaction (in food, honor, what have you).
- "Desires Fulfilled" *equally legitimately* implies a plenitude overfilled to surfeit, a luxury not **strictly** necessary or essential.

I think @Flonorec uses the right word with "expression". The extra words do work in disambiguation, methinks.

OK, time to stop procrastinating my real job... :)